# ubuntu core webdm alpha for Beaglebone Black not booting

Tags: beagleboard, ubuntu-core

I have tried the flashing SD card for Beaglebone Black with 'Ubuntu Core WEBDM' image i.e. 'ubuntu-core-WEBDM-alpha-02_armhf-bbb.img' as mentioned in the steps [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/things#try-beaglebone).

But the system is not booted. I have the following error captured in serial console. Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.

## From console:

```
Net:   <ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
cpsw, usb_ether
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
reading boot.scr
** Unable to read file boot.scr **
reading uEnv.txt
237 bytes read in 12 ms (18.6 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from mmc ...
Running uenvcmd ...
** File not found snappy-system.txt **
## Error: "snappy_boot" not defined
** File not found /boot/zImage **
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
SD/MMC found on device 1
reading boot.scr
** Unable to read file boot.scr **
reading uEnv.txt
** Unable to read file uEnv.txt **
Running uenvcmd ...
** File not found snappy-system.txt **
## Error: "snappy_boot" not defined
** File not found /boot/zImage **
## Error: "nandboot" not defined
U-Boot#
```

Comment: Sorry, but pre-release/development versions are off-topic here. Please ask on Launchpad.

Comment: @muru Is ubuntu snappy pre-release? I didn't know that.

Comment: @Seth a) Look at the image name that OP is using. b) From http://www.ubuntu.com/snappy: "... Ubuntu Core's rolling devel release, which is the only release available at present."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems *uEnv.txt* (on your SD card) is wrong. Change `${bootpart}` to `${mmcdev}:${mmcpart}`, i.e.

```
# where to load initrd
initrd_addr=0x88080000
# load Snappy environment and call into Snappy boot after processing this file
uenvcmd=load mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} snappy-system.txt; env import -t $loadaddr $filesize; run snappy_boot
```

This should fix the error "File not found snappy-system.txt" and allow U-Boot to continue.