# Ubuntu snappy not booting

Tags: boot, kernel, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu snappy on a BBB and after I've corrected the `uEnv.txt` as posted on [ubuntu core webdm alpha for Beaglebone Black not booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576227/ubuntu-core-webdm-alpha-for-beaglebone-black-not-booting) it freezes at `Starting kernel ...`. The full upboot output is:

> U-Boo dyn FIFOs, HB-ISO Rx, HB-ISO Tx, SoftConn) musb-hdrc: MHDRC RTL
>   version 2.0  musb-hdrc: setup fifo_mmory USB Peripheral mode
>   coata=0xde (UTMI-8, dyn FIFOs, HB-ISOde controller at 47401800 using
>   PIO, IRQ 0 OMAP SD/MMC: 0 mmc_se2013.04-dirty (Jul 10 2013 - 14:02:53)
>
> I2C:   ready DRAM:  512 MiB WARNING: Caches not enabled NAND:  No NAND
>   device found!!! 0 Mironment
>
> musb-c: 28/31 ma 0 musb-hdrc: ConfigData=0xde (UTMI-8, dyn FIFOs,
>   HB-ISO Rx, HB-ISO Tx, SoftConn) musb-hdrc: MHDRC RTL version 2.0 
>   musb-hdrc: setup fifo_mode 4 musb-hdrc: 28/31 max ep, 16384/16384
>   memory USB Host mode controller at 47401800 using PIO, IRQ 0 Net:    0
>   gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1 m found mmc0 is current device gpio:
>   pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1 Loaded environment from uEnv.txtreading
>   a/vmlinuz 5968320 bytes read in 74iB/s) reading a/initrd.img 12963231
>   bytes read in 1603 ms (7.7 MiB/s## Flattened Device Tre0f80000
>   Booting using the fdt bf80000    Loading Ramdisk to 9e5da000, end 9f
>   Starting kernel ...

Have any of you encountered this problem before?
I can successfully boot other distros out of SD card. Tryed re-wrinting the image to SD card as posted at http://www.ubuntu.com/things#try-beaglebone but the problem persists.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Does it work if you keep the button close to the SD card pressed?

Comment: Hi,indeed with the boot swth pressed while powering the BBB it does start :)Thank you